# Superlinearity in the definition of the Legendre transform

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose the Lagrangian $L:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfies the following conditions:

- $L$ is convex
- $$
  \lim_{|v|\to\infty}\frac{L(v)}{|v|}=+\infty
  $$

Define the Legendre transform of $L$ as
$$
L^*(p):=\sup_{v\in\Bbb{R}^n}\{p\cdot v-L(v)\}.
$$
It is said in Evan's *Partial Differential Equations* that the "sup" in the definition is really a "max". I don't see why this is true and I set it as an exercise. By the superlinearity, i.e., the second condition of $L$, 
$$
|p\cdot v|\leq |p||v|\leq L(v)
$$
for large enough $|v|$. I think this might be useful but I don't know how to get $v_0$ such that $p\cdot v_0=L(v_0)$ which would show that the "sup" is indeed a "max". Could anyone help me to go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

By choosing $v = 0$, we see that $L^*(p) \geq -L(0)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The superlinearity of $L$ implies that for each $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is $R > 0$ such that for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|v| > R$,

\begin{equation}
p \cdot v - L(v) < -L(0).
\end{equation}
We can therefore safely ignore any $v$ with $|v| > R$, and hence we know that

\begin{equation}
L^*(p) = \sup_{|v| \leq R }\{p\cdot v - L(v)\}
\end{equation}

Now as $L$ is convex, then $L$ is continuous, so $v \mapsto p\cdot v - L(v)$ is continuous.

As a continuous function on a compact set achieves a maximum, we conclude.